# The lattice item for some reason won't scale?

Tags: lattice

In the sense I'm trying to use this tool/addon on it refuses to scale in object mode unless it is in the add object menu.
I have tested out this in a new project to see if it was a problem in that accord but it's not, only in the item I am attempting to change if anyone has the solution it be great to know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It would be great to hear some more specfiics about this. What is the addon you are using? Also, a picture/description of the object you are trying to scale would be really useful. You may also want to consider uploading the .blend file for people to be able to help you better.

Comment: It is the basics the way it is when you open it, I tried earlier on a basic cube start up and it allowed me to scale the lattice without problems but if there is some other thing that you might know that stops this item from scaling? (My family doesn't have internet connection but I'm using a phone to say this so it's a bit difficult to get the file on.)

Comment: I found the problem a button that I didn't understand  "Manipulate center point (object, pose and weight paint mode only)  ;  shortcut: Alt"